# What is the benefit of using JDBC template?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jdbc, jdbctemplate

What is difference between JDBC Template and Hibernate?

I read somewhere JDBC Template gives benefit when we are working with bulk operation, is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

`JDBCTemplate` allows us to work with JDBC easily while `HibernateTemplate` allows us to work with Hibernate easily. For example, here is a method in `JDBCTemplate`:

```
<T> T   queryForObject(String sql, Object[] args, RowMapper<T> rowMapper)
```

You just need to prepare your SQL (passed via the sql parameter) and parameters (passed via args), define the `RowMapper` which converts the resultset to a object of type `T`. The `JDBCTemplate` will do the rest for you like: creating preparestatement, open the connection, execute the SQL code... If there is any error, the JDBC template translates it then wraps it in a `DataAccessException` etc.
Generally speaking, the `JDBCTemplate` facilitates our operations with JDBC.

As with the `JDBCTemplate`, When we work with Hibernate, the `HibernateTemplate` makes our operations easy.

You can get more information about JDBCTemplate [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-)

Answer (score 1):

Main thing , elimination of boilerplate code. In the old days when there was JDBC calls to be made on serverless environment , you always had 4-5 steps. Load the driver (Class.forName) , Get the Connection , Create the statement/prepared statement , Execute the query and get the ResultSet , iterate the resultset and get the results , close all handles you opened. Try catch SQLExceptions and other checked exceptions you get.

This got abstracted quite a lot , the Spring tooling allows you to manage a lot of these using configuration , simplifies and eliminates duplicate code and eliminates a lot of JDBC Errors.